# pydrive2: Is Authorize() needed after Refresh()?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive2

I'm writing a function that logs in a user to their Google Drive using OAuth 2.0. It returns the authenticated `drive` object. Here's my code:

```
def login_with_account():
    gauth = GoogleAuth()
    if 'credentials.json' in os.listdir():
        gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("credentials.json")
        if gauth.access_token_expired:
            gauth.Refresh()
        else:
            gauth.Authorize()
    else:
        gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
        gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("credentials.json")    

    drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

    return drive
```

My question is: Do I need to `Authorize()` after `Refresh()` as well or is this enough?
documentation link to `Refresh()` , can't find anything specific in the docs
https://docs.iterative.ai/PyDrive2/pydrive2/#pydrive2.auth.GoogleAuth.Refresh